# Kubernetes Pod communication through services

Tags: django, kubernetes

In the case that an app and database are in different containers/pods (each a separate deployment yaml) how do you get them to communicate?

For example, a Django app requires the host name of the database in it's config/environment variables (along with the database name and a few other things) in order to connect to the database.

You should be able to specify the service as follows (assuming the database has a service called db-service in the default namespace):

**Inside Django app demployment.yaml file:**

```
    env:
    - name: SQL_HOST
      value: "db-service.default"
```

or you could do some hackery with the HOSTNAME for the database container (if it's similar to the app name) for example:

**Inside Django app demployment.yaml file:**

```
env:
- name: POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name

- name: SQL_HOST
  value: $(POD_NAME)-db
```

**Inside Postgres demployment.yaml file:**

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sitename-db-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sitename-db-container
    spec:
      hostname: sitename-db
```

But what happens when you have multiple deployments inside a service for the same app (each having their app - database container pair)? How will the service know which app pod will communicate with what database pod? Does there now need to be a separate service for every app and database deployment?

Comment: You would create a service with a unique name for each pod/db you want to access.

Comment: A templating tool like [Helm](https://helm.sh) can help you create the matched pair of pairs of application and database deployments and services, and fill in the environment variable value in the YAML file for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what happens when you have multiple deployments inside a service
>   for the same app (each having their app - database container pair)?
>   How will the service know which app pod will communicate with what
>   database pod? Does there now need to be a separate service for every
>   app and database deployment?

What do you mean by *"multiple deployments inside a service"* ? In a `Service` definition you are supposed to select only one set of `Pods`, let's say managed by one specific `Deployment`. As @Matt suggested, you should always *create a service with a unique name for each pod/db you want to access*. If you have `Pods` dedicated to do specific tasks you deploy them separately (as separate `Deployments`). They can even consist of just one `Pod` if you don't need any redundancy. And basically you will always create a separate `Service` ( obviously with unique name as you cannot create more `Services` using the same name ) for exposing different microservice ( represented by unique `Deployment`). Note that if you don't create a `Deployment` but a simple `Pod` it won't be managed by any controller so if it crashes, nothing will take care of recreating it. So definitely you should always use `Deployment` even to run a single `Pod` representing your microservice.

Have you read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#creating-a-service) topic in official kubernetes documentation ? If you don't specify `Service` type, by default it creates so called `ClusterIP` Service which is basically what you need to expose your `app` components internally (make them available for other app components in your cluster).

Comment: Does this (service per deployment / pod) also apply for statefulsets pairs (statefulset for the database, and statefulset for the app)? Where each pair in the statefulset has slightly different configuration

Comment: `Statefulset` is the same abstraction layer as `Deployment` but it works a bit differently. You can read about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/). Both articles should give you enough knowledge to understand how it works and in which cases it can be applied. Basically you would use it for deploying stateful application such as database. For most apps `Deployment` would be still the best choice.

Comment: Note that `Statefulset` also needs a `Service` to expose its `Pods` but it uses so called `headless` `Service`, which doesn't have `ClusterIP` but exposes each `Pod` individually with unique `DNS` entry, so you can refer to them using these domain names in your app. *"Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling."*

Answer (score 0):

Expose backend as cluster Ip service (provide clusterIP: None in backend service definition file).

Now in frontend env var pass backend service name that you created